# Error obtain data with React and Solidity

Tags: reactjs, solidity

[image: Remix calling function]

**When call in my front (React)**

[image: Call on React]

My code:

```
const checkAllowance = await contract.GetAllowance.call({
                    from: account
                }).catch((error) => {
                    errorAlert(error.message);
                });
```

Comment: What is `Thanks in advantage`? Dwonvoted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number you get from that call is a `BigNumber`. Try to convert it with `.toString()`.